# photoshop cc: creating transparent patterns within text

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, transparency, patterns

I know how to create transparent text and have an image display within the text (clipping mask), but how do I create patterns (such as stripes) as transparent into text? Some examples:

[image]
[image]
[image]

These have text but also there are transparent stripes. I'd like to do something similar if its possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible in Photoshop.

1. Get yourself some seamless stripe patterns (.pat patterns). There are some here for free. http://www.deviantart.com/art/Diagonal-Stripes-Pattern-Set-210546266
2. Back in Photoshop, type the text in black.
3. Add a layer mask.
4. Select the layer mask by clicking on it in the layers panel, to select it.
5. Click Edit > Fill > choose "Pattern" as the fill, click on the down arrow next to the Custom Pattern - click on the tiny menu icon, and choose Load Patterns
6. Navigate to where you saved your pattern file. Load it. Select the pattern you want. Click OK.

[image: Screenshot adding stripes pattern to layer mask]

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use Illustrator in combination with Photoshop for this type of work. Illustrator works better with patterns and you end up with scalable artwork that can be used to generate print-ready resolutions.

Then in Illustrator, you create your patterns (many Youtube tutorials available) and then mask them inside words or letters. Copy your final artwork and paste into Photoshop to overlay on top of your product photos.

Objects will retain transparency when pasted from AI to PS.